# Connection between the fall of Jericho and Sukkoth

Tags: beis-hamikdash, sukkot, mizbeach-altar, haqafoth

Regarding the haqafoth (circumabulations) performed on Sukkoth around the mizbeah (altar), the Yerushalmi (Sukkah 4:3) records the following:

> אותו היום מקיפין את המזבח שבע פעמים.  א"ר אחא זכר ליריחו
>
> On that day [Hosh'ana Rabbah] they would circumbulate the altar seven times. R. Aha said
> that it commemorates Jericho.

What is the connection between Sukkoth and the fall of Jericho? Why is it uniquely commemorated on that holiday?

Comment: https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/13-05-09/